# Conjugacy of logistic and quadratic map?

Tags: dynamical-systems

Using the linear change of coordinates

y = h(x) = a + bx,

show that
f(x) = αx(1−x) on [0, 1], is equivalent to g(y) = β −y^2, on an interval [c, d],

for suitably chosen a, b, c, d.

In particular, what is the relationship between α and β for equivalence?

So it's a pretty simple question. You would just calculate h(f(x)) and g(h(x)) and find for which values they are equivalent which goes like this:

h(f(x)) = a + b(αx(1−x))

= a + bαx − bαx^2

g(h(x)) = β - (a+bx)^2

= β - a^2 - 2abx - b^2*x^2

hence

a + bαx − bαx^2 = β - a^2 - 2abx - b^2*x^2
would mean

a = β - a^2

bα = - 2ab

bα = b^2

meaning b = α  , a = (-1/2)α and β = (α/2)(α/2 - 1)

correct? Sorry, I don't have solutions and this is the first time I am solving a conjugacy problem. The difficult bit, is on what suitable interval [c,d] are these maps equivalent?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, could you please explain what this has to do with conjugacy? Or with covering spaces?

Comment: @Kenny, $f$ is $g$ conjugated by $h$: $f(x)=h^{-1}(g(h(x)))$. But nothing to do with covering spaces, I think.

Comment: Yes sorry, I mis-clicked covering spaces as a tag, it's gone now.

Comment: I edited to change to a more appropriate tag. Also, I suggest that you learn how to typeset your equations with MathJax https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.

Comment: My answer any use to you, Brandon?

Comment: You still here, Brandon?

Comment: Apologies, have been very busy with exam study. Yes your answer helped a lot, I've voted it and made it the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've done looks correct to me. The interval $[c,d]$ should be the image of the interval $[0,1]$ under the map $h$, so it's the interval $[a,a+b]=[-\alpha/2,\alpha/2]$ (if $\alpha>0$; if $\alpha<0$, then it's $[a+b,a]=[\alpha/2,-\alpha/2]$).